# Spark Structured Streaming ignore old records

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark and help me to arrive in solutions for this problem. I am receiving the input file it has information about an event occurred and the file itself has the timestamp value. Event Id is the primary column for this input. Refer below the sample input (the actual file has many other columns).

```
Event_Id | Event_Timestamp

1        | 2018-10-11 12:23:01

2        | 2018-10-11 13:25:01

1        | 2018-10-11 14:23:01

3        | 2018-10-11 20:12:01
```

When we get the above input we need to get the latest record based on event id, timestamp and the expected output would be

```
Event_Id | Event_Timestamp

2        | 2018-10-11 13:25:01

1        | 2018-10-11 14:23:01

3        | 2018-10-11 20:12:01
```

Hereafter whenever I receive the event information which has timestamp value less than the above value I need to ignore, for example, consider the second input

```
Event_Id | Event_Timestamp

2        | 2018-10-11 10:25:01

1        | 2018-10-11 08:23:01

3        | 2018-10-11 21:12:01
```

Now I need to ignore event_id 1 and 2 since it has the old timestamp that the state what we have right now. Only the event 3 would be passed and the expected output here is

```
3        | 2018-10-11 21:12:01
```

Assume we have n number of unique(10 billion) event id how it would be stored in spark memory, is there something needs to be taken care.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can take max timestamp and use persist() method with disk_only or disk_only2 storage levels... In that case, we can achieve this I think...
Since it's an streaming data, we can try with memory_only or memory_only2 storage levels too...

Please try and update..